# Ajax.BeginForm loading result in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to do an AJax form post, and when it is succesfull update a table with the results.

here is my code:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddTagToSubject", "Subjects", null, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "UpdateTableData();" }, null))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
    <div class="form-">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.Hidden("SubjectId", Model.Id)    
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label("Add Tag", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBox("Tag", "", new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

here is my script at bottom of page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       //Get the latest tags
        function UpdateTableData() {
            console.log("Called fucntion");         
        }
   </script>
```

Here is my action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> AddTagToSubject(AddTagToSubjectViewModel model)
    {
        model.Tag = model.Tag.ToLowerInvariant();
        var tags = await db.Tags.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == model.Tag);
        if (tags == null)
        {
            tags = new Tag { CreatedBy = User.Identity.GetUserId(), DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow, Name = model.Tag };
            db.Tags.Add(tags);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        var subject = await db.Subjects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == model.SubjectId);
        subject.Tags.Add(tags);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Json(subject.Tags.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now when I add a tag, it calls the action method everything works. It adds the tag to the db.  But on my front end, Instead of calling my `OnSuccess' function. It just reloads the whole webpage and displays my`JSON` result.

```
[{"Id":3,"Name":"Zulu"},{"Id":7,"Name":"accounting"},{"Id":6,"Name":"High School"}]
```

I have the following included in my layout file:

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"
                        ));
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It means that you have not included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` and maybe you have change your Ajax.BeginForm's OnSuccess function like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddTagToSubject", "Subjects", null, 
         new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "UpdateTableData" }, null)){...}
```

Comment: Helps if you include the bundle in the layout file. (Im a noob) My apologies